# Convert these Objects to int64 in python columns

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

Another simple question. I have to clean up some data, and a few of the columns need to be in int64 format instead of the objects that they are now (example provided). how would I go about uniformly re-formatting these columns.

```
print(data.Result)
0    98.8 PG/ML   H
1           8.20000
2    26.8 PG/ML   H
3    40.8 PG/ML   H
4            CREDIT
5          15.30000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse with regex:

```
import re

def parse_int(s):
    """
    A fast memoized function which builds a lookup dictionary then maps values to the series
    """
    map_dict = {x:float(re.findall('[0-9.]+',x)[0]) for x in s.unique() if re.search('[0-9.]+',x)}
    return s.map(map_dict)

data['Result'] = parse_int(data['Result'])
```

The function above takes all the unique values from the series and pairs them with its float equivalent. This is an extremely efficient approach in the case of repeated values. The function then maps these value pairs (`map_dict`) to the original series (`s`).

Comment: when I run the function, I get the error that the float function needs to be a string or number, not a list.

Comment: works perfectly. thank you. if you dont mind could you possibly explain a little more what is occurring?

Comment: Sure! I'll do so in the answer body. Also, feel free to accept the answer if you think it satisfies.